# Create multiple elastic search nodes in one Windows Server using MSI installer

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running an elasticsearch cluster in Windows server VM. I want to create a new cluster in the same machine for testing environment. Is this possible?
I have tried ways like
1. Adding new config1, data1, logs1 folder, added new values to elasticsearch.yml in config1 and config2 file and adding a new item in ES_PATH_CONF environment variable.
2. Running through the command line with command `bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=config` and for 2nd cluster `bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=config1`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: using zip file it would be much easier

Comment: I didnt get you Opster ES Ninja. Can you please explain

Comment: can u follow https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-windows.html and let me know if you have questions